# stacktrace on VS2010

Tags: c#

```
private void ParallelCrashTest() 
{

    for (int x = 0;x < 100; x++)
    {
        Dowork_1(i);
     }
}

private void Dowork_1(int i)
{
 ThreadInfo threadInfo = new ThreadInfo();
 threadInfo.first = 0;
 threadInfo.last = 100;
 for (int x = 0;x < 60; x++)
    {
        Dowork_2(threadinfo);
        progressBar2.Value = x + 1;   
    }
}
private void Dowork_2(object param)
{

    ThreadInfo threadInfo = param as ThreadInfo;
    int first = threadInfo.first;
    int last = threadInfo.last;
    Parallel.For(first, last, i =>
    {

        didsomthing...

    }

    Update();

}
```

So it doesn't work . (CPU is working 90-100 % it means i guess still working my app) 
 I used Update() instead of `Application.DoEvent()` . My application is crash or can not Update(). I don't know . I think that may be problem is Update() but i am not sure . Do you have any suggestion ? 
Thank you .

Comment: What is "didsomthing?"  I'll bet that whatever's causing this to crash is in there.  Probably trying to update the GUI.

Comment: @the fail troll is fail.  I also love the "MY APP CRASHED HURR" questions with *no exception details whatsoever*.  Like we can wave a magic wand and know why something crashed.  Also, Application.DoEvents in a multithreaded app?  Guy needs to sit down with a nice book and learn.

Comment: @Will: You mean you *don't* have a magic debugging wand?  I paid top dollar for mine but it was worth it, no more pesky application crashes!

Comment: @aaron I bought one but it turned out to be a magic *buggering* wand.  I was not happy.

Answer (score 2):

Crashing in what way?

My guess is that you are trying to update the GUI from another thread, such as to update the progress bar. To do this you must use `Invoke`.

It would be useful if you could provide a minimalistic simplified but complete example of compiling code that reproduces the error so that we don't have to guess. You could do this by copying your project into a new folder and removing unnecessary files, classes, methods and lines until it is impossible to remove any more lines while still reproducing the error.

Comment: Actually when i use sample "For" loop it was fine but it takes long time. So i need to reduce time. I just changed "Parallel.For" instead of "For" loop. I think that didsomething is doesn't matter coz it worked when i use "for" loop

Comment: @tonontlga: When you use `for` it runs in the same thread. `Parallel.For` is allowed to use many different threads. I think your problem is that you are updating the GUI inside the parallel for, but it could also be something else related to threading. You haven't provided enough code for me to be sure what the problem is. Try to make a compilable and runnable minimal simplified example that reproduces the error and post it.

Comment: Yeah i am using progress bar. My application is working for few minutes Suddenly it crashed I mean middle of the all live time of program.:)

Comment: @tonyontlga: it might also be a race condition. You can't just go round mindlessly changing `for` to `Parallel.For` just to make it go faster. It can change the semantics too as the code is not necessarily going to execute in the same order. You need to provide more code. The problem is almost certainly in the bit you missed out.

Comment: It would also be useful if you provided the exact error message and stacktrace rather than just saying it 'crashes'.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the Update() method nor the progressBar2.Value assignment are legal from a worker thread.  It won't crash Visual Studio, not even VS2010, you'll get a simple IllegalOperationException to tell you that you are doing something improper.

You'll need to use the [Control.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method.  There's a good example in the MSDN article I linked.

Comment: yeah i used worker thread . it's like Workaround process. But it takes long time inside of "paralle.for" loop. That's why it was not good. i have to arrange time schedule.